# Subclassing namedtuple vs implementing __slots__?

Tags: python, class, oop, python-internals

I'm currently trying to optimize a program that could benefit from a lesser memory footprint. Within that program are objects that store data and don't ever change their state, but they do however have functionality, for example:

```
class Extent:
    def __init__(self, xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax):
        self.xmin = xmin
        self.ymin = ymin
        self.xmax = xmax
        self.ymax = ymax
        self.center = ((xmin + xmax) / 2, (ymin + ymax) / 2)
    def contains(self, extent: 'Extent'):
        # checks if one contains the other
    def intersects(self, extent: 'Extent'):
        # checks if one intersects the other
```

In my search for memory savings, I came across `__slots__` which prevents classes from creating `__dict__` for arbitrary attribute assignment. This is great since I know what attributes the objects will have, so I can just add it in:

```
class Extent:
    __slots__ =  ('xmin', 'ymin', 'xmax', 'ymax', 'center')
    def __init__(self, xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax):
        ...
```

Then I started to explore `namedtuple`'s since they use a pretty small memory footprint, the downside is that I cannot add methods unless I subclass them:

```
Boundary = namedtuple('Boundary', ['xmin', 'ymin', 'xmax', 'ymax', 'center'])
class Extent(Boundary):
    def contains(self, extent: 'Extent'):
        ...
    def intersects(self, extent: 'Extent'):
        ...
```

But this will still allow for `__dict__` to be created, so we must explicitly state `__slots__`:

```
Boundary = namedtuple('Boundary', ['xmin', 'ymin', 'xmax', 'ymax', 'center'])
class Extent(Boundary):
    __slots__ = ()
    ...
```

So the question I have is what benefit is there to the last example (`namedtuple` subclass with `__slots__`) over the class that implements `__slots__` and doesn't inherit from anything?

Comment: Well, a `namedtuple` *is a `tuple`*. So if you want a sequence type, its a pretty good way to go. Otherwise, you probably just want a regular class with slots.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga How much of a contrast is there in the memory profile of a `namedtuple` subclass vice a regular class with slots?

Comment: If you really want to optimize for space, pack your data into a byte string and forgo separate Python objects altogether.

Comment: @chepner I've not even seen that suggestion, perhaps you can elaborate in an example or point to a reference?

Comment: Note that your implementation has `center` as an attribute or a field (one extra float stored per object).  For memory efficiency you may not want that, it could be a property instead (computed on the fly).

Comment: Subclass `typing.NamedTuple` and I think you won't have to define `__slots__`

Comment: Well, an instance of `Extent` basically consists of 5 integers. `struct.pack("!IIIII", xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax, center)`. Operations will be slowed down, as they'll have to unpack each value on demand.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I suppose I could, haven't had to do a memory profile check on a custom class so I'll have to spend some time searching how.

Comment: @wim Not sure what you mean by "a property"?

Comment: @pstatix you can use `import sys; sys.getsizeof(some_object)` were `some_object` can be an instance of whatever you want.

Comment: @alkasm Oh really? I'll have to look into that.

Comment: @chepner True. Trade off in terms of time vs space complexity. Still worth a look.

Comment: It's quick and dirty, but `sys.getsizeof` says a `namedtuple` instance takes up 80 bytes (in addition to the size of the integers it stores). If you're really concerned about the memory footprint of storing 5 integers, then any kind of data structure (nt, array etc) is probably a big enough overhead to just stick with variables.

Comment: The `array` class might be a better choice than my brute-force explicit packing example.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Can I? It was my understanding that `getsizeof` doesn't recursively check the size of an object. Thus a instance of a class containing a list as an attribute does not consider the _true_ size of the class, only the size of the object itself.

Comment: @chepner I have used that class in the past, may look into it as well.

Comment: @pstatix yes, so what? That's exactly what you are interested in. Will the size of the list change if it is an attribute of your named tuple subclass or your custom class? And of course it considers the *true size* of the class. It just doesn't recursively give you the size of everything in that object graph, which can be just as misleading as not considering it.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I was trying to determine the best approach for the complete instance in terms of memory consumption. That would include the size of all the objects inside of it.

Comment: @pstatix yes, but having slots or not *doesn't affect the size of the objects being referenced by your slotted/non-slotted object*.

Answer (score 2):

I will let your specific question of namedtuple x slots apart, and focus on your memory-saving problem. Because tuples x slotted attributes might, and will differ for a few bytes in size - but by using either, you have to hold full Python objects as the numbers themselves.

It is possible to have a class that would keep the data as packed bytes in an array, and lazily yield your attributes as Python numbers as needed. Memory wise that would be a winner, since a number in Python is a full-object with a minimum size of 24 bytes (on 64bit platforms).

If getting the numbers lazily becomes a performance problem, you could move your class to cython, and have operations use the natively packed numbers in each of your objects.

All in all, a valid approach might be a specialized Sequence class that will wrap a NumyArray with the data for your objects in sequences, and ephemeral objects that are retrieved as elements from this sequence.

The good news is that numpy already offers this functionality - it allows arrays to be composed of objects with a custom `dtype`, and there is even `np.void`a structure-type base class that is defined by its dtype - which can have additional functionality.

The code bellow can hold an "Extents" class inside a numpy array, with each instance taking exactly the number of bytes needed for the data. WIth the advantage that you can use extended numpy data-types -  for example, use "float32" ("f4"), if memory is a concern and a 32bit FP value is enough for you.

You could actually just use a raw np array with a custom dtype - this code shows how you can add some bells and whistles to have your "center" property, and be able to access xmin, etc...as attributes rather than only using the mapping syntax (seq[0]["xmin"]):

```py
from collections.abc import MutableSequence

import numpy as np


class Extent(np.void):
    attrs = "xmin ymin xmax ymax".split()
    dtype = np.dtype([(attr, "f8") for attr in attrs])

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return self.__getitem__(attr)

    def __setattr__(self, attr, value):
        if value in self.attrs:
            return self.__setitem__(self, attr, value)
        return super().__setattr__(attr, value)

    @classmethod
    def store(self, storage, xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax):
        storage.append((xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax))
        return storage[storage.last_item - 1]

    def contains(self, extent: 'Extent'):
        pass
        # checks if one contains the other
    def intersects(self, extent: 'Extent'):
        pass
        # checks if one intersects the other

    @property
    def center(self):
        return ((self.xmin + self.xmax) / 2, (self.ymin + self.ymax) / 2)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Extent <{self.xmin}, {self.ymin}, {self.xmax}, {self.ymax}>"


class ExtentList:
    def __init__(self, max_size):
        self.last_item = 0
        self.data = np.zeros(max_size, dtype=Extent)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return  self.data[index]

    def __setitem__(self, index, value):
        self.data[index] = value

    def append(self, extent):
        self.data[self.last_item] = extent
        self.last_item += 1

    def __iter__(self):
        for i in range(self.last_item):
            yield self.data[i]

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"ExtentList <{self.data[:self.max_size]!r}>, max={self.max_size}"
```

On the interactive terminal:

```py
In [63]: values = ExtentList(10)                                                                                                     

In [64]: v = Extent.store(values, 10, 10, 20, 20)                                                                                    

In [65]: v                                                                                                                           
Out[65]: Extent <10.0, 10.0, 20.0, 20.0>

In [66]: v.center                                                                                                                    
Out[66]: (15.0, 15.0)
```

Moreover - this approach allow your attributes to be mutable in-place:

```py
In [73]: v.xmax = 40                                                                                                                 

In [74]: v.center                                                                                                                    
Out[74]: (25.0, 15.0)
```

The ony drawback is that you can't resize numpy arrays as easily - so, I kee an internal index for the ending, and you have to set the max-size. If the max-size will vary too much, there are recipes around on how to resize numpy-arrays, and you'd have to add the logic to the container class to do that, inspired on the logic Python itself uses for allocating size for lists.